# Solr autosuggestion

Tags: solr, autosuggest

Having problem in getting suggestion for mobilephone i.e 2 words without space. 
for example, if search keyword is mobilephone, solr has to show suggestions like 
mobile phone in mobile
mobile phone in Electronics
mobile phone in All department

Comment: So what is your exact question? If you want to find mobile phone when mobilephone is typed use the SynonymFilterFactory.

Comment: you need to check how you are indexing the tokens for your auto suggester

Comment: Having around 1 million records, so we cannot add synonym for all the words

Comment: add an analyzer that removes spaces in front of an indexed (not necessarily stored)  field and you will have "mobile phone" when "mobilephone" (or "mo bilephone" "mob ileph o ne", etc) is typed. Although "phone mobile" would not match...